# Instructions Package for Java

Tags: java, swing, dialog, instructions

I want to make a help/instructions page for my Java program but I really don't want to have to go through and program all the frames and searching and such.  Is there a package or program that I can just insert the data into and it will read it and create the dialog?  I couldn't seem to find anything about it on Google.

It doesn't have to look like this at all but I like having the table of contents and the search at least.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/752f287397.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/752f287397.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java help system : https://javahelp.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 2):

The windows help dialog you show is part of the Window Help subsystem.  You could easily create a help file for that and launch it from your Java application, but it would be platform specific.  If you want to implement cross-platform help functionality, you're probably going to have to implement it yourself, but you could probably do it simply by including a set of HTML resources and using an embedded lucene index to supply search functionalty.

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using a simple HTML based manual and/or website where all that information may be accessed through?

Pretty much like http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/ for instance where you have a main page and you can navigate the topics from there?

If that's a website ( rather than a local /doc directory ) you can have the extra benefit from having a full featured search engine index it for you.

See also: [Google is the Help menu](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/google-is-the-help-menu.html)

After all, how many times do **you** use these help systems instead of searching the web?

Comment: "After all, how many times do you use these help systems instead of searching the web?"

lol never but this is a requirement for my project.